# Sparse symmetric positive definite matrix in Julia

Tags: math, julia

I am trying to create a random sparse symmetric positive definite matrix in Julia.

One approach I tried was:

```
n = 10
density = 0.1
X = sprand(n,n,density)
X = 0.5*(X+X') + n*eye(n)

@test isposdef(X) == true
```

This works but it gives you a diagonally dominant matrix which I don't want. The entries should all be from the same random distribution.

Comment: I think you'll need to specify the exact random distribution you want to sample from (the set of sym pos def matrices is non-compact so you can't be uniform).

Comment: On a related note you will need should be able to specify exactly what you want to do mathematically before worrying about how you can do it in a particular language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a sum of outer products of vectors, plus a (small, if you want) multiple of the identity, eg
`M = eps*I + X*X' + Y*Y' + .`.
Since an outer product is positive semi-definite then as long as eps>0 this will be positive definite.

Can you have a positve definite matrix where all the elements have the same distribution? I'd have thought not, as you couldn't guarantee, for example, that M[0,0]*M[1,1]>M[0,1]*M[1,0] as is required for M to be positive definite.